# How to use JTabbedPane inside JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

My program needs to have a `JTextArea` with scroll inside the `JTabbedPane` and `JTabbedPane` is kept within `JPanel`. The following is the piece of code I have tested.

```
private JTabbedPane jtab;
private JScrollPane jsp;
private JTextArea jtxta;

jtab = new JTabbedPane();
jtxta = new JTextArea();
jsp = new JScrollPane(jtxta);

jtab.addTab("[Untitle]", jsp);
main_jpn.add(jtab);

getContentPane().add(main_jpn, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

But there is nothing displayed when the program runs. What's needed in my program?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `getContentPane().add(main_jpn, BorderLayout.CENTER);` The call to `getContentPane()` has been unnecssary for quite some time (Java 1.5?).  Also it is generally recommended not to extend `JFrame` at all.  Just use an instance of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an example for you

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Solution extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTabbedPane jtab;
private JScrollPane jsp;
private JTextArea jtxta;

public Solution() {
    jtab = new JTabbedPane();
    jtxta = new JTextArea();
    jsp = new JScrollPane(jtxta);
    jtab.addTab("[Untitle]", jsp);
    jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    getContentPane().add(jtab, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setSize(300,400);
    this.pack(); 
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Solution();
}
}
```

The result is shown below

[image]

the most important is you need to set the scroll policy,keeping the scroll always shows.

Comment: 1) Swing and AWT GUIs should be started on the EDT.  2) Better than `this.setSize(300,400);`, suggest a size in rows and columns in the `JTextArea` constructor and `pack()` the frame before setting it visible. 3) I doubt this has much, if anything, to do with the scroll pane. 4) Nice screenshot.  :)

Comment: `this.setSize(300,400);
    this.pack(); ` O_o  Did you try that?  It should as far as I can see, reduce the frame to small again..  If packing a frame (and yes, we should), the size needs to be suggested by the components (and borders), which is best done (in this case) by specifying columns and rows for the text area..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the layout of main_jpn and the parent component to BorderLayout.

```
    JPanel main_jpn = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```